# Best way to Connect to SQL server 2000 with ASP 4.0 on .NET 4.0 build

Tags: c#, asp.net

Can I do this using SqlClient or do I have to use the ODBC route  > ? I get error's in VS but from reading through the other post it appears to be an IDE specific problem.

Comment: Please provide enormous amounts of detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Microsoft Enterprise Library 5.0, specifically the Data Access application block.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff632023.aspx

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/architecture/MS-EntLib-DataAccess1.aspx

http://jwalin.wordpress.com/2009/02/11/get-started-with-the-enterprise-library-data-access-application-block/

Answer (score 2):

The best way is to use ADO.NET which should work just fine. You should absolutely stay away from the ODBC route:

```
using (var conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=mySql200Server;Initial Catalog=myDataBase;User Id=user;Password=secret;"))
using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
{
    conn.Open();
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT count(*) FROM foo";
    var result = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
}
```

If this doesn't work here are the things to check:

- Your connection string is correct (serverName/database/username/password)
- You have access to the SQL server from within your ASP.NET server (verify network and firewall)
- Your SQL query is correct

Comment: Impressive! I didn't know it worked with Sql 200! :) Just kidding, it should work fine, I've done it in the past myself.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use SqlClient, and you shouldn't get any errors.